# How to fix StartupDelayInMSec trick does not work anymore?

Tags: windows-11, updates, delay, autostart

Until a few days ago I was able to remove startup delay for Autostart entries on Windows 11 with the known registry trick:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Serialize]
"StartupDelayInMSec"=dword:00000000
```

Since I disabled my updates for quite a while, I installed them then (now: 22H2 Build 22621.1992) and after that the trick refused to work. The delay is 10sec after logon from now on, no matter the registry value set. Windows simply ignores it.

I tried to remove and create the key and value called above again, ran "sfc /scannow", searched for updates again, did lots of restarts, disabled all other Autostart entries plus re-enabled them and checked state of fastboot (disabled as always): nothing had any impact on the delay.

**Does anyone know, whether its only my Windows 11 has an ugly bug or did Microsoft really removed the ability to remove delay? And even more important: Is there a fix for that?**

I have an autstart app depends on being executed straight after logon, thats why I ask for a fix in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows 11, this behavior is replaced with a more dynamic timeout based on the system being in a sufficiently "steady state", which seems defined by various metrics such as low enough CPU/disk activity.

To disable this behavior and go back to the old "StartupDelayInMSec" behavior, you can set a REG_DWORD called `WaitforIdleState` in the same place to `0`.

(source: `RunStartupAppsThreadProc` in disassembly of `explorer.exe`)

Comment: Thanks for investigating. Having both "WaitforIdleState" and "StartupDelayInMSec" are set to 0 reduces the delay from 18s to 8s (after login screen finished). But I want the autostart programs to be launched immediately after login (no other custom autostart apps defined, maybe the default ones take so long? - e.g. when adding cmd terminal in autostart it takes additional 3s for me).

Comment: Maybe the remained delay is more because of the hardware which is not the best, to be honest. Plus, since Windows 10 every app itself needs much more time to be processed than Windows on XP/Vista/7/8. Probably you can not do anything about the latter, can you? With "WaitforIdleState" you helped me a lot already, thats for sure.